# How to obtain an Intersection of a List of complex custom Objects and a List of its String attributes and in Java using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream, intersection

Here's my domain classes `Location` and `Address`:

```
public class Location {
    GPS gps;
    Address address;
    // etc.
}

public class Address {
    String street;
    String number;
    // etc.
}
```

Let's say I have a List of `String`'s

```
List<String> houseNumbers
```

and a List of `Locations`

```
List<Location> locations
```

Now, I want to have only those `Location`s where the `Location.address.number` matches with any of the `String`s in the `houseNumbers` list.

I've the following, which produces a compilation error: *"expecting a
`Predicate <? super java.lang.String>` instead of a String"*.

*My attempt:*

```
List<Location> filteredLocations = locations.stream()
    .anyMatch(location -> 
        housenumbers.stream().anyMatch(location.address.number)
    );
```

But how do I make sure to compare to every item in the `houseNumbers` List?

The following snippet did the trick:

```
List<Location> filteredLocations = 
 locations.stream().filter(
   location -> housenumbers.contains(location.address.number)
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ***But how do I make sure to compare to every item in the List houseNumbers?*** - Use `filter` instead of `anyMatch` .

Comment: With filter it is still complaining about the Predicate. locations.stream().filter(
location -> 
 housenumbers.stream().anyMatch(location.address.number)
)

Comment: When posting questions, please put in minimal code to demonstrate the issue.  That includes all classes and data structures required with input and expected output.  It should be in the form of a [mre].  And you should also take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the data from the `houseNumbers` into a `HashSet` a then in the stream check the house number of each `Location` against the Set.

For that, you would need to apply:

- `filter()` operation to discard the locations, which has a house number that is not present in the list;
- `toList()` as a terminal operation to collect the result into a list (or `collect()` with `Collectors.toList()` specified as an argument if you're using JDK 15 or earlier).

```
List<String> houseNumbers = // initializing the list
Set<String> numbers = new HashSet<>(houseNumbers);

List<Location> locations = // initializing the list
    
List<Location> filteredLocations = locations.stream()
    .filter(location -> numbers.contains(location.getAddress().getNumber()))
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList())
```

***Sidenote:** in Java, we use access modifiers to encapsulate the data properly withing the class. And getter methods serve a mean of accessing the data. Don't keep the fields `public` (or package-private). If you're doing a lot of JavaScript you might be accustomed to this `location.address.number`, but in Java it's not appropriate.

Comment: contains did the trick